# "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting" when pymysql cursor executing

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, pymysql

This is the first time for me to use pymysql cursor execute.
I have two executes;

The first one is:

```
sql = 'create table if not exists currency(t integer primary key, prediction real default null, realVal real default null)'
cursor.execute(sql)
```

This works perfectly.

The second one is:

```
data = [(1, 12.5), (2, 10.2)]
sql = 'insert into currency(t, prediction) values(%s, %s) on duplicate key update values prediction=values(prediction)'
cursor.execute(sql, data)
```

The issue arises here.
"TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting"

I have no idea why this happens. Anybody help me.
Thanks.

Comment: I'am not sure how you get this error with this query and data. This should throw a syntax error because the "values" between "update values prediction" is too much. And then you should get another error because the supplied data for `t` is not an integer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. BTW, I am not sure what do you mean "values b/w update values preduction is too much". And as I mentioned, the first sql execute exactly and create a table and I checked it on workbench. Would you please share me full code that is working correctly?

Comment: I've added a full answer, maybe this will make it clear now. Furthermore, I didn't understand yesterday that you probably want to insert multiple entries at once. Therefore my last sentence with the integer is probably a bit confusing, sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

everyone.

This is Mykola. I need to spend several days to fix this problem and finally figure out the answer.

This error only appears when I use **ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE**.

Actually there is no syntax or logic error.

This is just a bug in MySQLdb which is located in **usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/MySQLdb/cursors.py:**

```
restr = (r"\svalues\s*"
        r"(\(((?<!\\)'[^\)]*?\)[^\)]*(?<!\\)?'"
        r"|[^\(\)]|"
        r"(?:\([^\)]*\))"
        r")+\))")

insert_values= re.compile(restr)
```

To overcome this problem I have used two SQL clauses below.

```
sql = 'insert into currency(t, prediction) select %s, %s where not exists(select * from currency where t=%s)'
cursor.execute(sql, (1, 10, 1))

sql = 'update currency set prediction=%s where t=%s'
cursor.execute(sql, (12.5, 1))
```

If someone could make it better, please share.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your second statement has a syntax error. The second word "values" in your query was too much.

```sql
insert into currency(t, prediction) values(%s, %s) 
     on duplicate key update prediction=values(prediction)
```

Furthermore use `cursor.executemany()` to insert multiple entries instead of `execute()`.

So the complete code for the second query should be:

```py
data = [(1, 12.5), (2, 10.2)]
sql = 'insert into currency(t, prediction) values(%s, %s) on duplicate key update prediction=values(prediction)'
cursor.executemany(sql, data)
```